# Get method in magento2

Tags: ajax, magento2.2.2

Why the get method ajax call content like..

> /customer/section/load/?sections=messages&update_section_id=true&**_=1540902816229**

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

That's an ajax call that retrieves the session messages from the server.
It is done via ajax so the page can be cached and still get proper messages from your own session.

Comment: But it displayed only GET method calls

Comment: the session messages are added to the session via different actions (adding something to cart, writing a review, ...). The get request you see is called on every page and checks if there are such messages in the session. If yes, it displays them. if not...well.. nothing happens.